# Visual Studio Added Captions in wrong places

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My Visual Studio has started adding these strange captions in places where they don't belong. Is this an add-on that I have? How do I stop this? Maybe if I knew what these things were called I could research it but I don't even know where to start without a name.

[image]

On this page it appears to be working correctly, but if I can just turn it off for all pages that would be best as the places where it gets it wrong is quite annoying.

[image]

Comment: Is it consistently bad in the places it is bad?  What happens if you restart VS

Comment: That looks like the "inline hints" or "type hints" feature is broken - you should file a bug (via the Help menu) - but you can also disable it under Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Hints (it's near the bottom).

Comment: So far it hasn't come back. I restarted visual studio and came back with 120 errors because it lost access to all nuget packages.  After fixing that it hasn't started happening again yet, but this isn't the first time. I opened a bug report. I suspect I will be reinstalling visual studio soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress this display in all pages, as Dai said go to `Tools->Options->Text Editor->c#->advanced`

Disable [inline hins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Text_Editor.CSharp.Advanced)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022#inline-hints) and Inline Type Hints.

[image]